# How to add image to prepopulated tweet prompt

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'm building a website that prompts users to send a prepopulated tweet out upon successfully submitting a form. I'm trying to add an image that will automatically be added to that tweet, but having difficulty figuring out how.

Here's the markup that triggers the tweet prompt:

```
<input onclick="tweetIt()" class="exclude btn-main stack" name="user-submitted-post" id="user-submitted-post" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Submit + Twitter', 'usp'); ?>">
```

Here's the tweet function:

```
function tweetIt () {
  var phrase = 'Some text content';
  var tweetUrl = 'https://twitter.com/share?text=' +
    encodeURIComponent(phrase) +
    '&url=' +
    'http://xxx';

  window.open(tweetUrl);
}
```

Does anyone have experience with this? Any help is as always, greatly appreciated!

cheers,

Comment: I think you'd need to upload the media first, then include it using `media_ids`: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Comment: hmmm, good info there, but doesn't seem to apply in this instance, as far as I can tell.

Comment: it looks like your tweet text is being populated by php so I would start there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using the Twitter Card meta tags.
https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image